# How to disable the future date selection from DatePicker in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, datepicker

I am working on a Custom DatePicker in SwiftUI, for that I have written below code which is woking great -

```
struct DatePickerView: View {
    @State var searchDate = Date()
    let title = "Select a date"
    let dateChanged: (_ date: Date) -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        
            VStack {
                DatePicker(selection: Binding(get: {
                    self.searchDate
                }, set: { newVal in
                    self.searchDate = newVal
                    dateChanged(searchDate)
                }), displayedComponents: .date) {
                    Text(title)
                        .font(.headline)
                }
                .background(.bar)
            }
    }
}
```

Now I want to disable the future date selection, can someone help me to do that?

Answer (score 8):

It can be done with allowed range, like

```
   DatePicker(selection: Binding(get: {
            self.searchDate
        }, set: { newVal in
            self.searchDate = newVal
            dateChanged(searchDate)
        }), in: ...Date(),          // << here !!
            displayedComponents: .date) {
            Text(title)
                .font(.headline)
        }
```